# System language, can I change it after installation?

Tags: control-panel, language

I have Craft on local (Pro edition) that was installed with French as the system language.  Is there a way to change to another language (English for example) for the control panel? I want to change **the system language**, not the content of my entries (localisation).
[image: image of cp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Settings->Locales in the control panel, you can add "English - en" as a new locale/language to Craft.

From there, you can can what language the Control Panel will display on a *per user* basis by going to the user's account and setting the "Preferring Language" setting.

As [J. Baptiste](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/20058/57) pointed out, you can also set what the default Control Panel language should be for all users by setting the [defaultCpLanguage](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultCpLanguage) config setting.

Comment: thanks a lot. what i needed is "going to the user's account and setting the "Preferring Language" setting." compeleted the answer that i need :).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `'defaultCpLanguage' => 'en',` in `craft/config/general.php`
https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultCpLanguage

Comment: i tryied your solution but still no change at all, it's still in french...

Comment: Do you have "en" in Settings->Locales?

Comment: no, do i add it manually ?